# Custom Listview not removing right item

Tags: java, android, listview

I have made a custom list view which has a `checkbox`, two `edittext`, and an `imageview` which serves as a button.
when the `imageview` is clicked it should remove the list item where it belongs to, but  it removes the lowest item from the list.
i tried:

```
...
ArrayList<ListDetails> myList;
MyAdapter adapter;
...
class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter
...
public View getView(int pos, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
View v=convertView;
...
delBut=(ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.ivDelBut);
...
delBut.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
@Override
public void onClick(View v)
{
myList.remove(pos);
adapter.notifySetDataChanged();
}
});
...
```

Comment: You'll probably have to play around with the `parent` parameter as you have to remove the whole `View`. Take in account that positions are relative as Android recycles layouts.

Comment: how? i havent played around with ViewGroups yet and i seriously dont have any idea on how i would use that in my code, please expound.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the position as the tag of the button

```
delBut=(ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.ivDelBut);
delBut.setTag(pos);
```

And then in your onClick callback:

```
myList.remove((int) delBut.getTag());
adapter.notifySetDataChanged();
```

Comment: setTag takes two parameters: int i, Object o.
what should i do?
btw, it also takes one pareter but its object o so your suggested answer maybe invalid

Comment: well actually i'm sure you can set an `int` as a tag, as I do that myself for various reasons.

Comment: A primitive int will be wrapped in an Integer object by [Autoboxing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html). You just have to be careful to cast it back to an int when you use `getTag()`, as I did on my answer.

Comment: the set tag thing worked for me, but, it still didn't andswered my question.